# Drawing Shapes in C# Not Working

Tags: c#, forms

I have a C# program that I am trying to draw a GUI for. This program is a 2D array where each spot in the array can have a different type of `Space` object: `Asteroid`, `EmptySpace`, or `GravityWell`.

My `SpaceProbeView` class will get passed the 2D array and then draw a small rectangle in each space on the form with a different color depending on the `Space` object.

I have run into the problem that my program doesn't actually draw anything. I can add a random rectangle and draw that from the Graphics object, but that is all that will draw. Am I doing something wrong? I am totally new to Windows Forms.

Here is the `SpaceProbeView` class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    class SpaceProbeView : Form
    {
        private int squareSize;
        public int SquareSize
        {
            get { return squareSize; }
            set { squareSize = value; }
        }

        private Space[,] map;
        public void setMap(Space[,] aMap) { map = aMap; }

        private int mapSize;
        private int rowSize;

        public SpaceProbeView(int numberOfSpaces)
        {
            mapSize = numberOfSpaces;
            rowSize = (int)Math.Sqrt(mapSize);
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(mapSize *5, mapSize * 5);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            for(int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++)
            {
                for(int column = 0; column < rowSize; column++)
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(map[row, column].getBrush(), row * SquareSize, 
                        column * SquareSize, SquareSize, SquareSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `Space` interface is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    public interface Space
    {
        SolidBrush getBrush();
    }
}
```

with the code for one of the `Space` subclasses, `EmptySpace` (adding all the subclasses seems unnecessary, they all follow this pattern):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    class EmptySpace : Space
    {
        private static EmptySpace instance = new EmptySpace();
        public static  EmptySpace Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
            set { }
        }

        private SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DeepPink);
        public SolidBrush getBrush() { return brush; }

        private EmptySpace() { }
    }
}
```

and the `Map` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    class Map
    {
        private Space[,] map;

        public Space[,] TheMap
        {
            get { return map; }
            set { }
        }

        public Map(int size) 
        {
            map = new Space[size, size];
            Random random = new Random();

                for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < size; column++)
                    {
                        //TODO: make this so that it enforces the right quantity of each, not just a vague percentage
                        int randomInt = random.Next(11);
                        if (randomInt <= 1)
                            map[row, column] = GravityWell.Instance;
                        else if (randomInt > 1 && randomInt <= 7)
                            map[row, column] = EmptySpace.Instance;
                        else if (randomInt > 7 && randomInt <= 10)
                            map[row, column] = Asteroid.Instance;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and it is all run in:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Map map = new Map(10);
            SpaceProbeView view = new SpaceProbeView(100);
            view.setMap(map.TheMap);
            Application.Run(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Put a breakpoint in your paint method, step through it. Is it executing any of the FillRectangle calls?

Comment: @Blorgbeard It lets me step into the getting of the brush but then just steps over the call to FillRectangle. So, it's at least executing the stuff in the parentheses, but I'm not sure about the actual FillRectangle call.

Comment: have you gone through FilllRectangle method ? I think problem is there.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yysstebh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: My suggestion - First try to draw predefined set of objects with hard coded arrays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this actually a *complete* code example? If so, then your problem is that you never initialize the `SquareSize` property. Since it's `0`, your rectangles are empty, and so of course nothing gets drawn when you call `FillRectangle()`.

As long as I'm here :), I would also recommend some other changes. For example, the following is more idiomatic C# (not Java-like), and also includes better implementation practices:

```
class EmptySpace : Space
{
    private static readonly EmptySpace instance = new EmptySpace();
    public static EmptySpace Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    private static readonly SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DeepPink);
    public SolidBrush Brush { get { return brush; } }

    private EmptySpace() { }
}
```

In other words, you should use real properties when you have property-like semantics. Also, if a field should never be changed, declare that with `readonly` (similar to `final` in Java, at least in this context). Finally, you might as well make the `brush` field static, since even if you had more than one instance of `EmptySpace` (I know, you won't), all instances would share the same brush.

Same thing goes for other `Space` subclasses, including making `brush` fields `readonly` and `static` as appropriate.

I'll also note that classes that hold on to disposable resources like `Brush` should implement `IDisposable`. And of course, you should dispose instances of those classes when you are done with them.

In your `SpaceProbeView` class:

```
    private Space[,] map;
    public void setMap(Space[,] aMap) { map = aMap; }
```

Again, better would be:

```
    private Space[,] map;
    public Space[,] Map
    {
        get { return map; } // avoid write-only properties
        set { map = value; }
    }
```

Because it's used for both rows and columns, this:

```
    private int mapSize;
    private int rowSize;
```

Should be:

```
    private int mapSize;
    private int rowAndColumnSize;
```

(or something similar…just make clear that it's used for both)

This code, I don't really understand:

```
    public SpaceProbeView(int numberOfSpaces)
    {
        mapSize = numberOfSpaces;
        rowSize = (int)Math.Sqrt(mapSize);
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(mapSize *5, mapSize * 5);
    }
```

I thought I understood the initialization of `mapSize` and `rowSize`, but then I saw the initialization of `Size`. Where did the `5` come from? Why is the size of your form 5x as large as the total number of spaces, rather than just the number of spaces in either dimension (rows or columns)?

Given the usage, I would have just had the `map` object passed to the constructor. While the code you have here works as long as the caller passes a valid value for `numberOfSpaces`, you don't really have any way to ensure it matches the actual dimensions of the `map` object set later.

If you pass the `map` object itself, then the row and column dimensions can simply be retrieved from that object, and you don't even have to require the caller to pass a square map. You could probably get rid of the `mapSize` variable altogether in that case; it's not clear at all why you have it anyway.

Comment: That was thorough. Thanks.